# How can I make my android device think I am somewhere else in the world

Tags: gps, amazon-appstore

I want my android device to think my phone is in The U.K so I can buy stuff in U.K pounds cheaper.

I have set up my google wallet for the U.K. And sure enough the prices display in U.K pounds,  I've installed Amazon underground and the prices in Amazon underground display in pounds, but when I download apps and open them the prices are still in U.S dollars.

Or I have a "you are not eligible to purchase this app due to geographical restrictions".

I have all gps location sharing off, using wifi, and my google wallet is set up to the U.K

Any help out there?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to settings> About Phone.
2. Click on build number seven times to activate developer options.
3. Go to Settings>Developer Options.
4. Enable Mock Location.
5. Download any mock location app such as "Fake GPS" from the play store.
6. Go to the developer options again.
7. Select Mock location app and choose the app you downloaded.
8. turn off GPS. Open the app and select your new location.

If it does not work, probably the content provider is using your IP address to check your location. In that case, use a VPN service to spoof your location.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to make Location Sharing fake your location (it doesn't give out your real location, but still doesn't update status with the fake one).

Comment: @Ruslan have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: @wild_nothing unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

I use the TunnelBear VPN software for my Android 4.4 phone and Android 5.0 tablet.

I first used it when the Beeb showed that Edward Snowden interview that could not be viewed outside the UK.  It worked just fine.  Interesting interview; I have not yet seen it on American television.

You can find it at http://www.tunnelbear.com
They allow you to use up to 500 MB per month for free to try it out.

It supports many countries around the world.  Speed is fast enough to watch Netflx with it.

I use http://www.grc.com Shields-Up to verify the IP address it uses in various places around the world.  I'm sure https://panopticlick.eff.org would work for this, too.

Once you know your VPN address you can do a traceroute (or Visual Trace) to see where you "are".

The best part is that on an Android it encrypts and tunnels ALL traffic.  So as my Androids grabs onto the open WiFi at church it is all encrypted just like at home.  It looks to the world like I am in another time zone.

On a PC it operates in Chrome and Opera by way of browser extensions, but all other traffic goes native.

I like it so much I paid their fee for unlimited data and never have turned it off.  Being in the USA I find it prudent to only use the US connection so I am not crossing foreign borders.  It can be switched very quickly and easily if I needed it for some special task.  Even then I would stay within the USAUK countries only.  But so far I have not had any reason to utilize anything outside the USA.

Bottom line is that it provides full-time encryption and tunneling for my Androids, and my virtual IP never reveals my actual state as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a "fake GPS" app there are plenty on the Google play store. I recommend the one entitled "fake GPS" by Lexa apps. The icon is a yellow ball emoticon. You will also need to enter developer mode. Find your menu containigthe device vital information, tap on the section mentioning the Kernel approximately a half dozen or so times. You've activated developer mode!! Here's a gold star ...

Next under Dev menu, find the mock location  setting and set the app as your default.

You can also use a VPN. some of them don't really work, but VPNTUNNEL.Com is affordable, reliable and actually works in changing your geoip.